# Create a toggle button within a tkinter class

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-class

I'm trying to create a Tkinter class that has a toggle button.  My code is something like the following.

'''
'''

```
from tkinter import *
class test:
    window = Tk()
    window.title("Start/Stop Button")
    window.geometry('200x100')

    def clicked_rf1():
         if btn_rf1['text'] == "Start":
            btn_rf1.configure(text="Stop")
            lbl_rf1.configure(text="  ON  ", bg="green")
         else:
            btn_rf1.configure(text="Start")
            lbl_rf1.configure(text="  OFF ", bg="red")

    btn_rf1 = Button(window, text="Start", command=clicked_rf1)
    btn_rf1.grid(column=1, row=1)
    lbl_rf1 = Label(window, text="  OFF ", bg="red")
    lbl_rf1.grid(column=2, row=1)

    window.mainloop()
```

This gives me an error that says btn_rf1 is not defined in clicked_rf1().

If I run this code without defining it as a class, it works.  I think it is because 'btn_rf1' is a class attribute instead of a variable in a class and caused this issue, but I'm not sure how to fix it.  Appreciate any help

Comment: Please post the error traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
from tkinter import *


class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.title("Start/Stop Button")
        self.window.geometry('200x100')
        self.btn_rf1 = Button(self.window, text="Start", command=self.clicked_rf1)
        self.btn_rf1.grid(column=1, row=1)
        self.lbl_rf1 = Label(self.window, text="  OFF ", bg="red")
        self.lbl_rf1.grid(column=2, row=1)

        self.window.mainloop()

    def clicked_rf1(self):
         if self.btn_rf1['text'] == "Start":
            self.btn_rf1.configure(text="Stop")
            self.lbl_rf1.configure(text="  ON  ", bg="green")
         else:
            self.btn_rf1.configure(text="Start")
            self.lbl_rf1.configure(text="  OFF ", bg="red")


app = Test()
```

You aren't using classes properly. Read [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp) tutorial to learn more about python classes and how they work.